# Returning certain items of two lists at a time

Tags: python, list

I am currently getting used to working with lists. I was wondering if the following can be done: Suppose we have two lists, L and M, where

```
L = [4743, 20517, 13104, 14330, 18597, 13311, 946, 7696, 3357, 509, 10271, 17032, 512, 8859, 16265]
M = [14925, 24993, 34483, 12033, 23966]
```

Is there any  way I get n (from 1 to 5) number of items from L and get 1 item from M, that is:

```
4743
14925
20517
13104
24993
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `while` loop until both the lists have some value, then get a random integer `n` that is either between 0 to 5 or `len(L)` if list size is less than or equals 5, and pop `n` items from the list `L` from left, and 1 item from list `M` at zero index.

```py
import random
L = [4743, 20517, 13104, 14330, 18597, 13311, 946, 
     7696, 3357, 509, 10271, 17032, 512, 8859, 16265]
M = [14925, 24993, 34483, 12033, 23966] 

while L and M:
    count = len(L) if len(L)<=5 else 5
    n = random.randint(0, count)
    print([L.pop(0) for _ in range(n)])
    print(M.pop(0))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[4743, 20517, 13104, 14330, 18597]
14925
[13311]
24993
[946, 7696, 3357, 509, 10271]
34483
[17032, 512, 8859, 16265]
12033
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, one way using `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

it = iter(L)
res = []
for n, i in enumerate(M, start=1):
    res.extend(islice(it, n))
    res.append(i)
```

Output:

```
[4743,
 14925,
 20517,
 13104,
 24993,
 14330,
 18597,
 13311,
 34483,
 946,
 7696,
 3357,
 509,
 12033,
 10271,
 17032,
 512,
 8859,
 16265,
 23966]
```